# I am having some difficulties in using Getx state management with a screen for placing orders

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, state-management

I have an app to track sales of a store, and I have a screen that's used to insert orders, this is to ensure that no mistakes happen by the cashier as well as to make sure that no order is forgotten, anyway I am facing some troubles incorporating getx's state management, here is how my OrderScreen look like :

```
class OrderScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const OrderScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Dish>>(
        future: DishCache().getDishes(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          // Case 1: Data is still loading
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }

          // Case 2: Data loading failed
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
          }

          // Case 3: Data loading completed successfully
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
              snapshot.hasData) {
            List<Dish> dishes = snapshot.data!;

            return Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(width: 30),
                      const Expanded(
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'Place an order',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 28, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
                        onPressed: () => Get.back(),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 10),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: dishes.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index1) {
                      return SizedBox(
                        height: SHelperFunctions.screenHeight() * 0.4,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemCount: dishes[index1].sizes.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index2) {
                            return OrderCard(
                              title: dishes[index1],
                              size: dishes[index1].sizes[index2],
                              imagePath: getDishImage(dishes[index1].dishType),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 40)
              ],
            );
          }

          // Case 4: Data is null or empty
          return const Center(
            child: Text('No data available'),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton.small(
            heroTag: null,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            shape: const CircleBorder(),
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Icon(Iconsax.close_circle),
          ),
          Card(
            shape:
                RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
            color: Colors.white,
            elevation: 5,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
              child: const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0, vertical: 2),
                child: Text(
                  '000 DA',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          FloatingActionButton.small(
            heroTag: null,
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            shape: const CircleBorder(),
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Icon(
              Iconsax.tick_circle,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }
}
```

[here is how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htdnc.png)

and as u can see am using a custom widget named OrderCard, here is it:

```
class OrderCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Dish title;
  final DishSize size;
  final String imagePath;

  const OrderCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.size,
    required this.imagePath,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int quantity = 0;
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0, right: 8.0),
      child: Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
        elevation: 5,
        child: Container(
          width: SHelperFunctions.screenWidth() * 0.40,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Text(
                title.name.capitalizeFirst!,
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              CircleAvatar(
                maxRadius: 50,
                minRadius: 50,
                child: Image.asset(imagePath, height: 80),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              Text(
                size.size,
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 25),
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      quantity--;
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Iconsax.minus),
                  ),
                  CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: quantity == 0
                        ? Colors.lightBlue[150]
                        : Colors.lightBlue[300],
                    child: Text(quantity.toString()),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      quantity++;
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Iconsax.add),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem am facing is that i don't know how to incorporate GetX controller to handle each card by it self, as well as the full order details, so i can calculate the totals and insert the order to the database when the tick button is clicked

I have made some attempts at this but none of them work, if you have worked on something like this please share your experience, even if you have some different approaches am up for that too. And sorry if I have poorly explained the situation, am more than willing to further clarify or add more code snippets, and thanks in advance.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz iv'e just finished watching the video and it did point out some major flaws with Getx, but i still think that the scenario that am facing can be managed using GetX don't you think?